# Select From List Where Condition Exists in a Second List

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I have 2 customer lists and I'm trying to get a list of customers that DO NOT have a matching Name property between the 2 lists. I also need to include the customers from the second list that DO match, but that do not have the source property set to "migrated". Basically I would have a list of customer to add and update. I've tried a bunch of ways, but when I add the conditional for Source I end up with the wrong results. I'm doing it this way to have the ability to migrate in batches.

```
var legacyCustomers = new List<Customer>{ 
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 1" },
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 2" },
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 3" },
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 4" } 
};

var currentCustomers = new List<Customer>{ 
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 1", Source = "migrated" },
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 2", Source = "migrated" },
    new Customer() { Name = "Customer 3", Source = "" }  
};
```

In this scenario I need "Customer 3" and "Customer 4" added to a new Customer list.

Here's a fiddle I've been using https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z0RoFe

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the extra condition to your `Where` clause (i.e. where the names don't match or the source does not equal "migrated"):

```
var migrateList = legacyCustomers
    .Where(c => currentCustomers.All(c2 =>
        !string.Equals(c2.Name, c.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        !string.Equals(c2.Source, "migrated", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
        ))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This produces correct results, but has a O(n²) computational complexity.

Answer (score 3):

The code becomes a little bit simpler if we implement `IEqualityComparer<Customer>`. That means we're creating a class that uses custom logic to determine if two customers are equal.

```
public class CustomerNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x?.Name, y?.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return obj.Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

According to this class, two customers are equal if they have the same name. The convenience is that we can use this comparison without actually modifying the `Customer` class, since this might not *always* be the way we want to compare customers.

We can do it without this, but it results in a lot of complicated `Where` functions that compare the names. If you're going to compare items using specific comparison logic then it's easier to create the comparison once and re-use it.

If we did this (given that `firstList` and `secondList` are both List):

```
var customersFromFirstListNotInSecondList = firstList.Except(secondList);
```

It wouldn't work because it would use reference equality to compare the two lists instead of looking for matching names. But if we do this:

```
var customersFromFirstListNotInSecondList = 
    firstList.Except(secondList, new CustomerNameEqualityComparer());
```

It will compare the customers in the two lists just by matching their names.

That comparer class also makes the second step easier to implement:

```
var matchingButNotMigrated = 
    firstList.Intersect(secondList, new CustomerNameEqualityComparer())
        .Where(customer => customer.Source != "migrated");
```

This returns the items that are on both lists (intersection), again comparing using the names. Once it has the items that are on both lists it excludes those that are migrated.

Comment: This is awesome and I will try this. However I did already mark the answer. Thanks for this though!

Comment: I forget about this all the time - this question reminded me.

Comment: Your query returns Customer 1, Customer 2 and Customer 3. The OP wants as a result the customers 3 & 4. Upvoted anyway because of the nifty `CustomerNameEqualityComparer` class. 

Comment: @RyanOC You're welcome to change the selected answer if you find that another one is better.

Answer (score 1):

You literally just need to add a logical OR and check for the "migrated" string.

```
var migrateList = legacyCustomers.Where(c => currentCustomers.All(c2 =>
    !string.Equals(c2.Name, c.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
    || c2.Source != "migrated")).ToList();
```

There's no need to do any additional check on the name since any non-matching names are already included, so the extra condition will only be adding names that do match but have a Source of "migrated".

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) method produces a O(n) solution.

```
var comparer = new CustomerNameEqualityComparer();
var results = legacyCustomers
    .Except(currentCustomers.Where(customer => customer.Source == "migrated"), comparer);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {String.Join(", ", results.Select(c => c.Name))}");
```

Output:

> Customer 3, Customer 4

I am using the elegant [`CustomerNameEqualityComparer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925516/11178549) class created by [@Scott Hannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5101046/scott-hannen).

```
public class CustomerNameEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Customer>
{
    public bool Equals(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x?.Name, y?.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Customer obj)
    {
        return obj.Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```